# Configuring iptables to let Docker containers access out

Tags: centos, iptables, docker

I've got a CentOS server running Docker and I'm trying to secure it using iptables. And I can't work out how to let containers access the internet, without their ports being accessible from outside.

I've stopped Docker messing with my iptables using the '--iptables=false' command and am now struggling to configure iptables manually.

I want to set up the firewall so that:

- Inputs are dropped unless I specifically open them
- Containers can communicate with each other via the localhost connection
- Containers can make connections to the internet to download code etc

I have the first two, but whatever I try to enable the third invalidates the first!

I have two test containers. An httpd container forwarding its web output port 3333 - and another container running Debian.

IPTables is configured with

```
 iptables -P INPUT DROP
 iptables -P FORWARD DROP
 iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

 iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

So from outside I cannot access myserver:3333. 
But I can run from the host: curl localhost:3333 and have access.

I then added:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

And now I can run in my debian test container curl 172.17.0.1:3333 and that works fine too.

But if I'm in the test container and try: curl httpbin.org/ip I get no response.

I was reading on https://fralef.me/docker-and-iptables.html and tried the suggested:

```
iptables-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

With these I can now curl out from the test container, but this opens up 3333 to the world too!
How do I configure iptables to allow the container to access out, but prevent access in?

Comment: Any reason not to use firewalld?

Comment: I'd read some people claiming firewalld was better for desktop configuration than server. Although I've come to question that with further reading. 

Secondly I've found a lot more help on the iptables side of things that firewalld. But if there's good sources/advice I'll take a look!

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7 as intro, http://www.firewalld.org for reference, https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Firewalld?rd=FirewallD for a detailed (!) explanation.

Comment: Thanks!
Now I understand what I was doing wrong in IPTables, I'll have a look into doing the same in firewalld

Answer (score 2):

The solution which I found, which seems to provide what I want is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This seems to allow

- Communication among docker containers
- Communication from containers to the internet (through eth0 on my server)
- Communication back in response (related/established)

But, access to these ports is not opened to the outside world.

I think my problem was that I didn't understand that the Related/Established instruction I had added to INPUT didn't translated to FORWARD.

Answer (score 1):

The default firewall behaviour will serve you well. To limit outgoing access, use a proxy with ACLs on destination domains. You can even limit access based on the container; I made some functionality to do this last week using Squid’s ident ACL type and a custom ident server that returns the name of the container.

Details at https://distracted-it.blogspot.co.nz/2017/11/provisioning-limited-access-via-squid.html

You would also need to prevent your container server from making connections directly without going via the proxy.

Comment: Interesting answer. You've left me with quite a lot to learn and I'll continue to look into it.

I'd hope there's a more straightfoward way to allow docker containers to access the outside world without having to open them up to access in return.